# Set option page inside newtab chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a Chrome extension which modify the Newtab. 
Now i'm facing an issue with the option page.

I want it in the footer of my newtab. 
Example: in the footer of my newtab, I want to let the user decide which kind of content view in his newtab.

Is it possible or should i create an option page mandatorily?

Comment: Of course it's possible, see [an example extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/humble-new-tab-page/mfgdmpfihlmdekaclngibpjhdebndhdj). What's the problem?

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, with a manifest analyzer i've found the solution in your example extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm, i've found the solution.
So the answer is: YES, it is possible. 
You should add in your manifest.json these lines of code:

```
...
"options_page": "newtab.html#options",
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "newtab.html#options",
        "chrome_style": false,
        "open_in_tab": true
    },
...
```

Where #options is the ID of the div which your options is located.

Hope can help somebody :)